# how to delete history project in google appsript?

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

[image]
I cannot delete the project history in Google Apps Script. I've tried to delete it multiple times, but for some reason, I'm unable to do so. I'm uncertain why. The pop-up message reads:

> 'You cannot delete this version because it is being used by several deployments,'

as shown in the image